# Runtime exception while trying to parse date time using joda DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, jodatime

I am executing following code which gives me

`"Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "12/17/2017 23:10": Value 23 for clockhourOfHalfday must be in the range [1,12]"`

```
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
System.out.println(dt.parseDateTime("12/17/2017 23:10"));
```

If I will parse `"12/17/2017 02:10"` then It executes successfully.

So basically, I need to parse time having 24hr clock format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`h` is for halfday in JodaTime as you can see in the exception.
You need to use `H` (or possibly `k`):

```
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(dt.parseDateTime("12/17/2017 23:10"));
```

There is more information in the [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) API.

Comment: (It's the 12 hour clock in SimpleDateFormat too...)

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with Simple Date Format too.

```
DateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = readDate.parse("12/17/2017 23:10");
DateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(writeDate.format(date));
```